# How to start a math blog?

Tags: soft-question, online-resources

I'd like to start a blog where I can write mathematics related notes. The intended audience is mainly myself, but I don't mind it being available for public viewing. I'd like to keep setting up, installation, etc. down to the bare minimum, and edilikewise cost. While blog hosting services are a dime a dozen, they don't usually allow for the smooth integration of math and text, as on this forum, for instance. Any tips will be much appreciated.

EDIT: After exploring several alternatives (see my comment to [Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/232/qiaochu-yuan)'s answer below), I've settled on Blogger + Math Jax (see Antti Yrjonen's [step by step guide](http://www.weighingtheuniverse.com/2012/05/how-to-enable-latex-equations-in.html), including Sobresaliente's comment to it).

Why Blogger rather than WordPress? Because [WordPress.com does not enable to install the Math Jax plugin](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/using-mathjax-in-wordpresscom?replies=8).

Why do I need the MathJax plugin for? What's wrong with WordPress's native LaTeX support? For one, I'd like to be able to copy-and-paste between this forum (math.stackexchange.com) and my blog.

Comment: wordpress supports LaTeX. http://en.support.wordpress.com/latex/

Comment: Searching for "math jax" and seeing what resources it supports is probably a first step

Comment: wordpress/blogspot are your best options.

Comment: The step by step guide link doesn't work.

Comment: I use wordpress.org + MathJAX and all is well: http://stackexchange.moderatenerd.com/

Comment: I have also set up a math blog back in February, 2014 using blogspot and mathjax. I have to say I am quite pleased. It intended for me first of all to have an online place to write my notes down but as time passed I made it public so that everyone can read it and contribute it they want.

Comment: @Dahn Here is a working link: http://holdenweb.blogspot.com/2011/11/blogging-mathematics.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wordpress is a fairly straightforward answer. There are already many math blogs on it, e.g. [Terence Tao's](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/) and [Tim Gowers'](http://gowers.wordpress.com/). Requires minimal setup.

Comment: Thanks. I've given Wordpress a whirl and it seems like what i've been looking for. I've also found a list of promising online LaTeX editors on [Dave Richeson](http://divisbyzero.com/2012/12/05/online-latex-editors/)'s blog. From my cursory trials, writeLaTex seems especially appealing since it updates automatically while maintaining the page scroll position. However, it doesn't have a zoom feature.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want such a complex panel or want to start simple.

Just make an account on "http://blogger.com" or "https://www.tumblr.com/". They are very straight forward. And later you can move on to a professionally managed platform if you start getting a lot of traffic.

Comment: I might add that it's possible to [add MathJax to blogger](http://mathjaxtest.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score 3):

There is a new platform called [Functor Network](https://functor.network)
this year. It is specifically designed for writing a math blog. It supports not only formula typesetting but also automated numbering and bibliography. It even supports using various latex packages. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Gorgeous, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As of 2023, the best options for creating mathematical blog posts (also programming documentations, journal papers, thesis, presentations, books, ...) include the following tools:

- [Quarto blog](https://quarto.org/docs/websites/website-blog.html) using Quarto markdown file `.qmd` ([video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLkrJrLs7xfbXcEKhTCKRSr2VXH4yiBeXo))
- [Blogdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/) using Rmarkdown file `.Rmd`

Quarto is described as a "next generation" of Rmarkdown.

Some of their key features:

1. Markdown syntax
2. Latex syntax for Maths expressions (including macros, equation and citation references, ...)
3. Embedded R code for programming (with the capability to run Python, Julia and more)
4. Export to various output files: `.pdf`, `.html`, `.docx`, ...

The following figure briefly explains how Quarto works:

[image]

**Note.** [Typst](https://typst.app/) a next generation of LaTeX and Markdown will also be a great candidate in the near future that you should keep track.