# Is it a good idea to create a math blog on Wordpress?

Tags: soft-question, online-resources

I recently started a blog on Wordpress and ran into a lot of problems. These include

- Wordpress.com doesn't allow installing new plugins, so the user must pay a monthly fee to host the blog on Wordpress.org.
- $\LaTeX$ [support on Wordpress](https://en.support.wordpress.com/latex/) doesn't support equation alignment. Writing multi line equations is a mess.
- Writing math on a blog appears to be much more difficult than writing math in $\LaTeX$ .
- The blog writer has to adjust the font size of every line written in $\LaTeX$ . The default font size is extremely small.

Are these valid concerns about creating a math blog? Do all users who create a math blog run into the same problems?

It looks like I need to start self-hosting my blog [per these recommendations](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-use-LaTeX-Mathematical-notation-for-equations-in-my-free-Wordpress-blog) and download the WP to $\LaTeX$  plugins to work around these frustrations?

The blog I wrote is at https://axion004.wordpress.com/. I'm writing the blog for fun and would like to write more.

A similar question was posted previously, [How to start a math blog?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/343957/how-to-start-a-math-blog/343972#343972). I made a new question since I am looking for a slightly different answer.

Comment: I wish that stackexchange would launch a blog platform, using their latex support and upvoting system.

Comment: @Axion004, what did you end up doing? I see you are writing blogs these days.

Comment: @hi15 I'm currently a second year graduate student at UIC (http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~mkehoe5/). I'm studying applied/computational mathematics. I want to spend more time on my blog in the future.

Comment: @Axion004 nice! Also, what are using to write in latex in your wordpress blog?

Comment: @hi15: Latex2Wordpress. You can download it from  https://lucatrevisan.wordpress.com/latex-to-wordpress/download/. I write all of my posts in latex and then type python latex2wp.py my_file.tex at the command line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's mine: https://justanothermathblog.wordpress.com

I wouldn't recommend it, unless there's a new $\LaTeX$ plugin/integration/etc. I don't know about. My process for writing a blog post:

1. Write the post as a normal $\LaTeX$ document.
2. Use [LaTeX2WP](https://lucatrevisan.wordpress.com/latex-to-wordpress/using-latex2wp/) to convert the $\texttt{.tex}$ file into HTML, e.g.
   $$\texttt{python latex2wp.py input.tex output.html} $$
3. Copy the HTML into Wordpress and publish.

It works, but there's probably a content management system more suited for $\LaTeX$-based posts.